# Annotations in grails with Dropwizard metrics not working

Tags: grails, aop, dropwizard, metrics, graphite

I'm configuring dropwizard metrics for a grails application with annotations. Using metrics-aspectj plugin (https://github.com/astefanutti/metrics-aspectj)

I have the following in `BuildConfig.groovy'

```
compile 'io.astefanutti.metrics.aspectj:metrics-aspectj:1.1.0'
compile 'io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:3.1.0'
compile 'io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-graphite:3.1.2'
compile 'io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-annotation:3.1.2'
```

Here I'm trying to post data to `Graphite` server, running on local.
I have configured a controller as follows with graphite reporter. When i run the app it doesn't report anything, I'm trying to figure out where im going wrong, or please let me know, if there is an another approach (eg. using spring AOP)

```
import com.codahale.metrics.ConsoleReporter
import com.codahale.metrics.MetricFilter
import com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry
import com.codahale.metrics.SharedMetricRegistries
import com.codahale.metrics.annotation.Metered
import com.codahale.metrics.annotation.Timed
import com.codahale.metrics.graphite.Graphite
import com.codahale.metrics.graphite.GraphiteReporter
import io.astefanutti.metrics.aspectj.Metrics

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

@Metrics(registry = "graphiteregistry2")
class GlassdoorController {


    final MetricRegistry registry = new MetricRegistry();

    GlassdoorController() {

        final Graphite graphite = new Graphite(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 2003));

        final GraphiteReporter reporter = GraphiteReporter.forRegistry(registry)
                .prefixedWith("grails.example.com")
                .convertRatesTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .convertDurationsTo(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .filter(MetricFilter.ALL)
                .build(graphite);
        reporter.start(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        ConsoleReporter reporter1 = ConsoleReporter.forRegistry(registry)
                .convertRatesTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .convertDurationsTo(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();
        reporter1.start(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

        SharedMetricRegistries.add("graphiteregistry2",registry);
        log.info(SharedMetricRegistries.getOrCreate("graphiteregistry2"));
    }

    @Metered(name  = "reviewspage")
    @Timed(name = "reviewspagetimed")
    def reviews() {

        //business logic

    }
```

Comment: can you see any data with tcpflow incoming on 2003 from the app ?

Comment: AFAIF, the `ConsoleReporter`  and `GraphiteReporter` should print same data, I get empty lines when `ConsoleReporter` prints something

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I spotted a difference:

```java
reporter.start(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
// ...
reporter1.start(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

That means your Graphite reporter fires every second, but the console reporter only every 5 seconds. Probably your test program exists before those 5 seconds are over. So you can either add something `Thread.sleep(6000)` to your `main()` method or reduce the reporting interval for the console reporter to match the Graphite reporter. I tried, it works. `;-)`

```
06.03.16 12:22:59 ==============================================================

-- Meters ----------------------------------------------------------------------
de.scrum_master.app.GlassdoorController.reviewspage
             count = 1
         mean rate = 0,20 events/second
     1-minute rate = 0,20 events/second
     5-minute rate = 0,20 events/second
    15-minute rate = 0,20 events/second

-- Timers ----------------------------------------------------------------------
de.scrum_master.app.GlassdoorController.reviewspagetimed
             count = 1
         mean rate = 0,20 calls/second
     1-minute rate = 0,20 calls/second
     5-minute rate = 0,20 calls/second
    15-minute rate = 0,20 calls/second
               min = 0,01 milliseconds
               max = 0,01 milliseconds
              mean = 0,01 milliseconds
            stddev = 0,00 milliseconds
            median = 0,01 milliseconds
              75% <= 0,01 milliseconds
              95% <= 0,01 milliseconds
              98% <= 0,01 milliseconds
              99% <= 0,01 milliseconds
            99.9% <= 0,01 milliseconds
```

Comment: Did you made it work in grails, I  have got it working with pure java, but not with grails, if you have made it working with grails,  let me know

Comment: I do not use Grails, but could reproduce the symptom with pure Java. Have you investigated if the long timespan could be the problem? I cannot imagine that if it works with Graphite but not on the console, Gradle or Groovy should be the problem. I suspect the problem is in front of the keyboard.